# What does the shap interaction value of a feature with itself mean?

Tags: shap, interpretation, feature-interaction

SHAP allows us to compute interaction effects by considering pairwise feature attributions. This leads to a matrix of attribution values representing the impact of all pairs of features on a given model prediction

$\Phi_{i,j} = \sum_{S \subseteq N \backslash{i,j}} \frac{|S|!(M -  |S| - 2)!}{2(M-1)!}\nabla_{i,j}(S)$

where

$\nabla_{i,j}(S) = [f(S \cup  \{i,j\}) - f(S \cup  \{j\})]- [f(S \cup  \{i\}) - f(S)] $

SHAP interaction effect between the i-th and j-th is split equally (i.e. ϕᵢⱼ=ϕⱼᵢ) and the total interaction effect is ϕᵢⱼ + ϕⱼᵢ

**What does the following mean?**

The main effect for the prediction can then be obtained as the difference between SHAP value and the sum of SHAP interaction values for a feature:

$\Phi_{i,i} = \phi_i - \sum_{j \neq i}\Phi_{i,j}$